# Reloading List of Bitmaps

Tags: android, bitmap

I have an initialization activity that loads ~10 bitmaps over the network. The bitmaps are stored in a static variable and then the main activity is started. After pressing back or home from the main activity and then navigating back to the app, the initialization process starts over. Looks like my main activity is being destroyed as soon as onPause() is called. I've tried serializing the bitmaps, but they're too big. What's the best way save and restore this many bitmaps without having to go through the initialization process again?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a disk cache to store them see the Android Training class [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html), lesson [Caching Bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html#disk-cache).

Comment: haha dunno how you managed to dig this one up, but thanks, I'll look into that.

Comment: hehe yeh, was just searching for something similar and saw it was unanswered :)